# pandas reading csv file encoding error

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

i have a iso8859-9 encoded csv file and trying to read it into a dataframe.
here is the code and error I got.

```
iller = pd.read_csv('/Users/me/Documents/Works/map/dist.csv' ,sep=';',encoding='iso-8859-9')
iller.head()
```

and error is

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc4 in position 250: ordinal not in range(128)
```

and code below works without error.

```
import codecs
myfile = codecs.open('/Users/me/Documents/Works/map/dist.csv', "r",encoding='iso-8859-9')
for a in myfile:
    print a
```

My question is why pandas not reading my correctly encoded file ? and is there any way to make it read?

Comment: So if you have working code (because `codecs` can translate it for you), what is the question?

Comment: Actually, I need to read this file with pandas, I showed codecs code to prove my file is correctly encoded.

Answer (score 0):

Not possible to see what could be off with you data of course, but if you can read in the data without issues with `codecs`, then maybe an idea would be to write out the file to UTF encoding(?)

```
import codecs
filename = '/Users/me/Documents/Works/map/dist.csv'
target_filename = '/Users/me/Documents/Works/map/dist-utf-8.csv'
myfile = codecs.open(filename, "r",encoding='iso-8859-9')
f_contents = myfile.read()
```

*or*

```
import codecs
with codecs.open(filename, 'r', encoding='iso-8859-9') as fh:
  f_contents = fh.read()

# write out in UTF-8
with codecs.open(target_filename, 'w', encoding = 'utf-8') as fh:
  fh.write(f_contents)
```

I hope this helps!